# Django Dynamic Formset : Submit Value not Cloned

Tags: django, button, dynamic, submit, formset

i am trying to use [django-dynamic-formset](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/) library to dynamically add forms to a formset. The library clones the form pretty well but it is not able to clone the `value` attribute of the `submit` input for some reason.

following is the formset that i am using `django-dynamic-formset` on.

```
{% if eduforms %}
    {% for form in eduforms.forms %}
    <div class="formset-form">
        <form id="{{ form.prefix }}" method="POST">
            <h4>Add a Project</h4>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <div class="button-container right">
                <input class="button" type="Submit" value="Update Information" />
            </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready ( function(){
                jQuery('{{ form.prefix }}').validationEngine();
            });
        </script>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

i have tried binding the function to the div#`formset-form` container as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.formset.js"></script>                                                                            
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset-form').formset();
</script>
```

is there something i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why would you want to clone the submit button? You only need one per set of forms.

Comment: hmm, makes sense. But what i am trying to achieve is submit each form in the formset separately and remove the form instance as soon as it is submitted and an instance is created successfully, so that i can add it to the edit table in the same template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is use the `keepFieldValues` option of the jquery plugin that you are using and it will clone the values as well. So change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset-form').formset();
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset-form').formset({
        keepFieldValues : 'input:submit',
    });
</script>
```